# Show a div upon selecting an option. onchange="submit()" makes it not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery code that displays a div upon selection of an option in a dropdown list. It is working fine but not as I need. the problem is that upon selecting the option, the page refreshes as there is an `onchange="submit()"` on the select. That makes the div appears for about half second and then disappear again when the page is loaded

**Sample HTML:**

```
 <select onchange="submit()">
     <option id="one" value="something">Car</option>
     <option id="two" value="anything">Plane</option>
 </select>

<div id="somediv" style="display:none;">This is a string.</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('select').change(function(){
  decide($(this));
});
var decide = function (elem) {
    var touch = elem;
  if (touch.val() === 'anything') {
   return $('#somediv').css('display', 'block');
  }
};
```

I want the div to be displayed when the option of `id="two"` and `value="anything"` is selected, and to remain displayed after the page refreshes. When the user selects the other option, the div disappears and remains hidden after the page refreshes. How can I achieve this please? All answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `submit()` from the `onclick` and submit after you call the `decide` function

Something like:

```
 <select>
     <option id="one" value="something">Car</option>
     <option id="two" value="anything">Plane</option>
 </select>

<div id="somediv" style="display:none;">This is a string.</div>
```

JS:

```
$('select').change(function(){
  decide($(this));
  $('form').submit();
});
var decide = function (elem) {
    var touch = elem;
  if (touch.val() === 'anything') {
   return $('#somediv').css('display', 'block');
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested that but still the same problem. Any other suggestion?

Comment: you removed the `onchange="submit()"`?

Comment: Yes I did that, and also cleared the browser's cache but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```js
// define the function:
function showIfSelected() {
  // 'this' is passed in by jQuery, and is the <select> element,
  // this.options is a NodeList of the <option> elements of
  // the <select>, this.selectedIndex is the index of the selected
  // <option> from amongst that NodeList:
  var opt = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

  // finding all <div> elements with a 'data-showif' attribute:
  $('div[data-showif]')
  // hiding them all:
  .hide()
  // filtering that collection of <div> elements, to find the one
  // whose 'data-showif' attribute shares the value with the <option>:
  .filter('[data-showif=' + opt.value + ']')
  // showing that <div>:
  .show();
}

// binding the showIfSelected() function as the change-event handler:
$('select').on('change', showIfSelected)
// triggering the change event (to show/hide the correct <div>
// on document ready:
.change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option id="one" value="something">Car</option>
  <option id="two" value="anything">Plane</option>
</select>

<div id="somediv" data-showif="anything">This is a string.</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - Attribute selectors.
    *jQuery:
  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that partially works. It is showing the div without submitting the selection and I have to submit it manually. So, I have to make two manual submissions, one for the selection and one for the whole page _(The rest of the page has other fields)_ I was looking to submit the selection automatically then showing the div after page load if the selection was the second option. Is this possible? I hope you can help me with this. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use ajax to submitting your data, you should pass selected value via get/post or store it in a session/cookie then retrive it when the page loads.

Instead, if you use ajax you could do something like this

```js
$('select').change(function(){
    decide($(this));
    $('form[name=a]').submit();
})

var decide = function (elem) {
    var touch = elem;
    if (touch.val() === 'anything') {
        return $('#somediv').css('display', 'block');
    }
}

$('form[name=a]').submit(function(){
    $('#res').text('Submitted!');
    
    // Put $.ajax to submit your data
    return false; // Commenting this will result in a page refresh
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="a" method="post">
 <select>
     <option id="one" value="something">Car</option>
     <option id="two" value="anything">Plane</option>
 </select>
</form>

<div id="somediv" style="display:none;">This is a string.</div>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,it may works.

```
 <option id="one" value="First">Car</option>
    <option id="two" value="Second" selected="selected">Plane</option>
</select>
<div id="div1">This is a string</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select").change(function () {
            var v = $("select").val();
            if (v == "Second") {
                $("#div1").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#div1").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: That worked differently, the div remains appear when the second option is selected and that's what I want. But, when other option is selected, it disappears for less than second (while the page refreshes) and then shows up again.

Comment: <option id="two" value="Second" selected="selected">Plane</option>      By default the second option will be selected ,so after reloading your page it again displays the div content.